# oracle sql, using results of first query to perform second query

Tags: join, union, where-clause

I am  wondering if the following is possible:

Query  1: 
Select ID number FROM Contacts where Nam Like 'R%'

Query 2
Based on the select query results from query 1 I want to use the ID number results to perform another query right after the first query. Joining a lot of other tables. So for exampe:

Select ID number (From 1st query), schoolname, hobbies, schoolsubjects
FROM the tables school, hobby, subjects

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select ID number , schoolname, hobbies, schoolsubjects FROM the tables school, hobby, subjects where ID number in (Select ID number   FROM Contacts where Nam Like 'R%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by creating a table from your first query:

Create table interesting_ids as ...[your first query]

And select from that table in your second query. While it isn't what you asked, you could also obtain the same results with a single query, using a table join, a with clause, or a sub query.

Comment: You could think about putting the bits in your text where you use code in between ` `. That way readers will be able to easily discern text from code.